# Jmeter plugin error for PerfMonCollector listener while running Performance Metrics Collector

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to run performance test using jmeter in non-gui mode to map CPU/Memory Utilization for the server machine. However i am experiencing an error while running the test in non-gui mode.

```
    Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/Users/vikasgupta/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/Check FreePlays.jmx'. 
Cause:
CannotResolveClassException: kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector

 Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector
line number         : 266
version             : 5.0 r1840935
```

[PerfMon (Servers Performance Monitoring) plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pE4z.png)

[CannotResolveClassException: kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5zA8.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your test contains [PerfMon Metrics Collector listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) and your JMeter installation doesn't have this JMeter PerfMon Plugin.

Just install PerfMon (Servers Performance Monitoring) plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/) and you should be able to open the script.

[image]

If there are any other missing plugins - JMeter Plugins Manager will detect them and ask you whether it should download them

Comment: Hello @Dmitri T

I checked again whether i had the plugin installed already or not and i found that the PerfMon (Servers Performance Monitoring) plugin is already installed and present in the lib/ext folder.
I have attached another screenshot showing the same in the post itself. please check it once